# What would happen if a tungsten rod massing 1000kg slammed into the surface of Callisto at 15% of the speed of light?

Tags: planets, space

I am writing a sci fi story and I want to know what would happen if a tungsten rod massing 1000kg slammed into the surface of Callisto at 15% of the speed of  light? Given that there is a subsurface ocean what would the impact look like from afar, say half a million kms? Would there be a blinding light and steam and ejecta?

Comment: I think it would evaporate instantly.

Comment: Just so nobody else does the same calculation:  KE of tungsten rod ≈ $10^{18}$ J;  binding energy of Callisto ≈ $2 \times 10^{29}$ J.  So we're not talking moon-shattering effects, at least.

Comment: Also, for comparison, the yield of [Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba) was about $2 \times 10^{17}$ J according to Wikipedia.  But that was detonated in atmosphere, so I would expect the results to be different if a comparable amount of energy was suddenly delivered to the surface of Callisto.

Comment: see  https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because story-based what-if scenarios like this are more suitable for [worldbuilding.se]

Comment: [Link to question on WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/202650/what-would-happen-if-a-tungsten-rod-massing-1000kg-slammed-into-the-surface-of-c)

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/612624/59023