# Orbital collisions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, satellites, explosions

Russia destroyed a satellite.  TV news says the ISS will be at risk of the debris every ~90 minutes.

Seems to me that for the ISS to run into the debris, it must be going faster than the debris.  But if the debris is at the same altitude as the ISS, wouldn’t it have to have the same speed in order to stay at the same altitude?

Comment: This question is very similar to the following one: [Is it plausible that the explosion of a satellite in an orbit 65km above the ISS will not threaten the ISS?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/677543/)

Comment: While not exactly a duplicate, the other _does_ answer my question.

Comment: I added information to the linked to answer about the nature of the risk to the ISS